# Identify data file type

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad

I have a huge 1.9 GB data file without extension I need to open and get some data from. The problem is this data file is extension-less and I need to know what extension it should be and what software I can open it with to view the data in a table.

It's a 2 lines only file:

[image]

I already tried to import is as *csv* on Excel but it did not work, any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine file type in windows](http://superuser.com/questions/558914/determine-file-type-in-windows)

Comment: TRID helps you to determine what application/software this is, though this is not an application. its a "DATA FILE"

Comment: This looks like a stright text to binary write. ** In other words a program wrote printfs to a file stream.**  There is no extension because, first file extensions are not required, two this file doesn't have one.

Comment: I need a solution to open this data file in a table, this data was on mysql and I dumped it and I got this extensionless file, now I need to convert it to SQL or open it someway on a table. I do not care what file type this is.

Comment: Have you tried going back to mysql to see if it is possible to export the data as CSV?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a regular text file with Unix newlines? Some Windows text editors don't support Unix newlines and print them in one long line. Sublime Text should handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tools that can be tried. Two in particular are Qlikview that has a pretty good file parser to determine the data type and bring it to tabular format. Once Qlikview is able to get the data, you can export it to CSV. The second is Talend  Open Studio that you can use to predict source file structure. 
Unfortunately. You have to download both programs before you can test to see if your data is liberated. Well worth the try though